# Allow Makefile both append and override target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have base Makefile for all my services, in some cases I want to use my default "test" target, in other cases I want to override\add to it. These are the files I have so far (and obviously its not working as expect..).

MakefileBase

```
test:
    ./.../run-tests.sh
```

Makefile

```
BASE_FILE := /path/to/MakefileBase
include ${BASE_FILE}
test:
    @$(MAKE) -f $(BASE_FILE) test # un/comment this line in order to run the default tests.
#   echo "custom test"
```

When I run the test with the first line commented out I get the following

```
Makefile:10: warning: overriding commands for target `test'
/.../MakefileBase:63: warning: ignoring old commands for target `test'
echo "no tests"
no tests
```

except of the warning it works as expected, the problem is when I try to use the parent function then I get the following errors:

```
Makefile:9: warning: overriding commands for target `test'
/.../MakefileBase:63: warning: ignoring old commands for target `test'
make[1]: test: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `test'.  Stop.
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, both answers so far are wrong or incomplete:

`exit 0` in a rule will just exit the current shell (which runs only the `exit 0` command, so it is a no-op in this case). So this won't override.

It's not true that you cannot override a command without warning. If it is not necessary that both targets have the same name, you can do:

MakefileBase

```
.PHONY: test-base
test-base:
    echo base

%: %-base  # handles cases where you don't want to override
```

Makefile1

```
include MakefileBase

.PHONY: test
test:
    echo override
```

Makefile

```
include MakefileBase

.PHONY: test
test: test-base
    echo append
```

As with double colon rules, the effects of each targets (on each other) have to be considered, especially if you move away from `.PHONY` (for example, files considered up-to-date because the other rule just updated them).

BTW, I don't see the problem with your approach (aside from the warning). For me it worked fine.

Comment: with GNU make 3.81, the "%: %-base" has to contain at least command such as @true or it would not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [double-colon rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html) are for:

```
test::
        ./.../run-tests.sh
```

and:

```
BASE_FILE := /path/to/MakefileBase
include ${BASE_FILE}

test::
        @$(MAKE) -f $(BASE_FILE) test
```

This will "add to" an existing target.  There is no way to override a target with a different recipe without incurring a warning.

If you want to do that the only way is to use variables to hold the recipe then override the variable value.  For example:

```
test_recipe = ./.../run-tests.sh

test:
        $(test_recipe)
```

and:

```
BASE_FILE := /path/to/MakefileBase
include ${BASE_FILE}

test_recipe = @$(MAKE) -f $(BASE_FILE) test
```

Comment: It only adds the commands, if I try to add `test::
   echo "I want to do nothing at all"`
It will run the the command from the base make file and than echo

Answer (score 0):

Hacky, but you can get add, and a limited form of override that can never be deeper than one override. Both use double colon rules.

**add**: use double colons on both rules

**override**: use double colons on both rules, appending command `exit 0` to the last rule

```
# "addcmd" echoes "BA", "overridecmd" echoes "B"

addcmd ::
  echo "A"

addcmd ::
  echo "B"

overridecmd ::
  echo "A"

overridecmd ::
  echo "B"
  exit 0
```

Comment: Umm, what? Your "exit 0" will do exactly nothing, "overridecmd" echoes A then B. Same as "addcmd" in fact.